# Size of one DMA block

Tags: dma

When [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Memory_Access) is used, the whole block of memory is transferred from I/O device to main memory.

I am interested in the size of this block, more specifically in the answers to these questions:

1. Is the size of the block constant (if not, what are the conditions under which it changes)?
2. Is the size of the block determined by hardware or software or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the DMA transfer is programmed by writing a count register. Thus the size of the "block" is not constant, but is determined by software. This in general, there may of course be all kinds of special DMA controllers, with their own quirks, like constraints on the transfer size.